# Get access to Azure Blob storage and Key Vault from Azure ad B2C account

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault, azure-blob-storage

i'm new in Azure. And if the question is stupid don't punish me.
I made an App in Azure to get access to storage blob and key vault.
I used Azure AD tenant(with AD users) and user_impersonation scopes like https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation  and https://vault.azure.net/user_impersonation

All I need from that App is:

- Upload file to Blob
- Download file from Blob
- Delete file from Blob
- Generate SAS
- Get value of secret from Key Vault.

In Azure AD tenant it works fine. I can request to login.microsoftonline.com enter credentials and get token to my back-end to do all this things listed above.But later customer desided to use custom UX(to hide Microsoft login page) and only one way to get this is to use B2C and local accounts.

I made a B2C tenant like here [tutorial-create-tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant)

Registered App like here [tutorial-register-applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=applications) and add **Api permissions** to Azure Storage from **APIs my organization uses** tab

Created user-flows like here [user-flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows)

All local users in one group with Owner policy

Using this request i got a token

```
https:/<domain_name>.b2clogin.com/<domain_name>.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
p=B2C_1_signin&
client_id=<App_ID>&
nonce=defaultNonce&
redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms%2F&                         // https://jwt.ms/
scope=https%3A%2F%2Fstorage.azure.com%2Fuser_impersonation& // https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation
response_type=token&
prompt=login
```

In decoded token claim "aud" has id the same as Azure Storage API from **APIs my organization uses** tab when I register App, "scp" is "user_impersonation". But using this token i can't get access to storage using Postman (I use it as Bearer token)
For example GET request to https://.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list must return json with list of containers(and in Azure AD it work) but with this token got an error

```
<Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:49873755-401e-0065-0dd0-386211000000
Time:2020-06-02T11:24:57.3079213Z</Message>
    <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature validation failed. Signature key not found.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

May be I need to add additional Api access to Storage app some how?
What should I set up yet?
Or maybe there is a way to connect Ad B2C tenant to AD tenant?
Will appreciate any help.

**Upd:** as @juunas noiced I had differernt subscriptions for B2C tenant and Storage account. Now b2c and storage in one sub(i created new b2c, link subscription and move it inside b2c tenant, after that i made a storage account in moved subscription)

But the problem still exist.

I tried to change scope in request. On Api Permissions page in Azure Storage user_impersonation option you can see link like

```
https://*.dfs.core.windows.net/user_impersonation
```

when I used this link as a scope I've got an error

```
AADB2C90117: The scope 
'https://*.dfs.core.windows.net/user_impersonation' 
provided in the request is not supported.
```

After replacing of asterisk by name of storage account in link I've got the next message

```
AADB2C90205: This application does not have sufficient permissions 
against this web resource to perform the operation.
```

It looks like I need to get additional permissions for App?
Does it make sense? Or trying to get access to particular storage account is wrong?

Comment: Is your B2C tenant the same one that the subscription is linked to containing the storage account? Storage can only authorize the call if the tenant id matches in the token.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. B2C linked to the same subscription as storage account. Where i can check tenant id in token? Is it "iss" claim?

Comment: But _is the B2C tenant the tenant the storage account is linked to_?

Comment: How i can check it? I have only one subscription with B2C and Storage account. I can't create any of them with out sub.

Comment: If you have two tenants in Azure portal and you have to switch directory to manage B2C, then they are separate tenants.

Comment: @juunas it looks like you right. I checked subscription IDs from B2C and from Subscriptions page and they are different. I will try to reconnect B2C to my sub. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah.. This is a scenario I haven't really tested though. B2C users are basically AAD users so you _should_ be able to assign them access to the Storage account as long as the tenant matches. But I'm honestly not sure, B2C is often incompatible with stuff :\

Comment: @Dmitry Now Azure resources are projected by Azure AD. So if we want to access Azure resources, we need to od Azure AD auth. Regarding how to access Azure storage with Azure AD auth, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app

Comment: @JimXu thanks for your answer. In Azure AD all functionality is working. I need the same from B2C.

Comment: I would like to add same scenario. Create AD b2c account linked to own Azure keyvalut and blob storage. @Dimitry How did you solved the problem?

Comment: @MaciejPulikowski It's still impossible. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/35664649-azure-key-vault-compatibility-with-azure-ad-b2c